# Finding Employee's 2nd Highest salary in GRID DB

Tags: sql, griddb

I have got a technical requirement in my current project. I have created an employee table having 4 columns(Empid, empname, Department and salary).
I want to display Empid, Empname, Salary and the 2nd highest salary departmentwise. So can he write a code for this in GRID DB.
Please help me in writing this query in GRID DB

I tried using Dense_Rank() function.But want to understand whether this will work in GRID DB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to gridDB documentation (https://docs.griddb.net/latest/sqlreference/sql-commands-supported/#window-function), there's only one *window function* available, and that's ROW_NUMBER. Can I help? Not really, didn't even hear of gridDB until now; it wouldn't end well if I start suggesting code for it.